# Popup Window Close

Tags: visualforce, popup

I am have issue closing a popup window:

VF:

```
<apex:commandButton value="Close" onclick="CloseAndRefresh();return:true;" id="btn"/>

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
  function CloseAndRefresh(){
      window.opener.location.href="/{!$CurrentPage.parameters.id}";
      window.top.close();
 }
</script>
```

Also Popup i am calling frm Javascript button.  ie:

```
var j$ = jQuery.noConflict(); 
var recID = '{!User.Id}'; 
var iframe_url = '{!URLFOR("/apex/mypage?Id=")}'; 
var child_domain = iframe_url.substring(0, iframe_url.indexOf('/', 9)); 
var parent_domain = window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host; 
var j$modalDialog = j$('<div id="opppopup"></div>') 
.html('<iframe id="iframeContentId" src="' + iframe_url +recID + '" frameborder="0" height="100%" width="100%" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" scrolling="yes" />') 
.dialog({ 
autoOpen: false, 
title: 'popUp', 
resizable: true, 
width: 1050, 
height: 190, 
autoResize: true, 
modal: true, 
draggable: true 
}); 

j$modalDialog.dialog('open');
```

---

Can you please guide me for above problem.

Comment: I had also Face same issue earlier, please make sure your development mode should be turned off.

Comment: Hi Amit , Its already disabled. Please let me know if I am missing anything .

Answer (score 2):

Hello Rahul try this Way

```
 function CloseAndRefresh(){

          var newWin = null;          
          newWin =window.opener.location.href="/{!$CurrentPage.parameters.id}";

           if (window.focus) {
                newWin.focus();
           }
           if (newWin != null) {
                 newWin.close();
           }                               

}
```